# Is there a tool to build live recorded sequence diagrams?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

### Objective

Run an ASP.NET application, walk through a process, and get a sequence diagram back. One that would show me post backs and methods called - stuff like that.

### My Research

I've performed the following Google searches and haven't really found what I'm looking for. A lot of references talk about the built-in sequence diagramming in Visual Studio 2010 and up. Some talk about a third party sequence diagram generator. But I'm looking for something to let me walk through the process and then give me the sequence of events that occurred.

The second search turns up even less relevant results (not all that surprising), but it was worth a shot.

[Google Search 1](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=active&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net+sequence+diagram&oq=asp.net+sequence+diagram&gs_l=hp.3..0i30j0i8j0i8i30l2.381.3328.0.3689.24.17.0.7.7.1.283.2789.2j7j7.16.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.FnbpMMlmvdw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.dmQ&fp=d7b2718ad022bc29&biw=1257&bih=820)

[Google Search 2](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net+sequence+recorder&oq=asp.net+sequence+recorder&gs_l=hp.3...8068.9966.2.10079.9.9.0.0.0.3.390.1292.1j3j0j2.6.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.t4uA0D4qHtU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.dmQ&fp=d7b2718ad022bc29&biw=1257&bih=820)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing around with [ASP.net Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the information that you want on a request-by-request basis.

Comment: This is a pretty awesome set of information I didn't even know existed before! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/index.html) has a feature that uses the debugger to permit recording the steps of a program and to create a sequence diagram from that.

Comment: So it can (at some level) render the disconnected stage of a web application (i.e. the post backs and stuff). So you can get a feel for how the application is flowing?

Comment: I believe it will log all method calls.

Comment: That is fantastic! I'm going to get the approvals through my organization to download the free trial and I'm going to give it a shot. I'll let you know my findings!

Comment: The Sparx Systems website has a good video which introduces the Visual Execution Analyser tools of Enterprise Architect and covers sequence diagram recording (approx 5 mins in): http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/visualexecution/execution-analysis.htm

Answer (score 0):

At an http request/response level, I always fire up Fiddler2 - shows all requests/responses, multiple viewers, composer for firing raw requests, etc.

Not write a sequence diagram, but highly useful.